# VB6 shellexecute gets UAC - how do I prevent it?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

We have a VB6 program (developed over many years) that gets installed by us on customers machines.
I have now added a VB.Net program to the mix that gets run (ShellExecute'ed)from the VB6 program under certain circumstances (Does SQL access but does no file manipulation).

```
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
</requestedPrivileges>
<applicationRequestMinimum>
    <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetreference="FullTrust" permissionSetReference="FullTrust" />"
    <PermissionSet version="1" ID="FullTrust" unrestricted="true" SameSite="site" Unrestricted="true">
        <IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.FileDialogPermission, mscorlib, Version=1.2.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Unrestricted="true" />
    </PermissionSet>
</applicationRequestMinimum>
```

Is there any way that I can prevent customers machines (running W7/8/10) popping up the UAC dialog box?
The VB.Net prog has a Manifest that contains all the stuff that others have suggested and make no difference:

Any help gratefully received
Cheers
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Other than making the User an Administrator on the Windows 7 box, No.

Even as Administrators, they would need to completely deactivate UAC notification to avoid the UAC Prompt.